# Is it good to compare universities in motivation letter for student visa?

Tags: graduate-admissions, germany, visa, application

I'm a computer science student from Iran. I'm applying for student visa to study master in Germany. Germany's embassy requires students to write a motivation letter in visa process.

> For the summer semester 2016 I have received admission from TU
>   Darmstadt, TU Stuttgart and university of Freiburg. Also I have been
>   rejected from TU Dresden. For the reason of course contents, I have
>   chosen to study in TU Darmstadt.

I have written above paragraph in my motivation letter. Is this considered negative to write such things (compare universities or list my admission results)?

Comment: If you do leave that in (and it seems reasonable to me, but I've never had to apply for a visa) why mention Dresden at all?

Comment: @Rup No idea. Just want to be honest with embassy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I were you, I would just write why I want to study at TU Darmstadt. Have a look at their web pages, name a few courses you find interesting and a few professors you'd like to study with. I think that may be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You should write a *motivation* letter. I.e., you are interested in studying in Germany because <list of reasons>. In particular, you want to study at TU Darmstadt because <list of classes, orientation of the study, ...>. And you have been accepted there. After graduating, your plans are <...>, which relates to the selected university/study in the following ways <...>.

Put yourself in their shoes. *Why* is it advantageous **for Germany** to have you as a student? Are you interested in learn more about the German culture (apart from your studies)? How will you fit into a (presumably quite alien) environment? What is your proficiency in German and in English? (German is obviously needed for day-to-day contact, in and out of your studies; English is the lingua franca of anything related to technology).

Presumably the conditions are that you must return to your home after the study. How will that work out? Will you be able to continue work with colleagues in Germany, maintain contact with classmates?